# Using remove option with interactive docker container

Tags: docker

When testing with docker, I don't see any functional differences between the following two commands:

docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 bash
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash

By differences, I mean that the docker container started without the '--rm' doesn't show up in 'docker container ls' or 'docker container ps' after I exit the terminal. Is it necessary to use the --rm option when attaching to an terminal with the -it option? Is there a corner case that I'm not understanding where the --rm is required to clean up the container?

Apologies if this has been asked before. Seems like a simple enough question, but I had a tough time tracking down a related post. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try `docker ps -a`, which will also show stopped containers.  The form without `--rm` should be leaving them behind.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ah. This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks! You're correct that the exited containers still remain. --rm is very much necessary.